# rewrite T-SQL bitwise logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bit-manipulation

How do I rewrite this T-SQL code to produce the same results

```
   SELECT   ACC.Title,
            ACC.AdvertiserHierarchyId,
            1 AS Counter
    FROM    admanAdvertiserHierarchy_tbl ACC
    JOIN    dbo.admanAdvertiserObjectType_tbl AOT ON AOT.AdvertiserObjectTypeId = ACC.AdvertiserObjectTypeId
              WHERE  (EXISTS
                         (SELECT 1
                          FROM    dbo.admanAdvertiserHierarchy_tbl CAMP
                          JOIN    dbo.admanAdvertiserAdGroup_tbl AG ON CAMP.AdvertiserHierarchyId = AG.AdvertiserHierarchyId
                          JOIN    dbo.admanAdvertiserCreative_tbl AC ON AC.AdvertiserAdGroupId = AG.AdvertiserAdGroupId
                          AND     CAMP.ParentAdvertiserHierarchyId = ACC.AdvertiserHierarchyId
                          WHERE   CAMP.ERROR = 0
                                  AND AC.Dirty & 7 > 0
                                  AND AC.ERROR = 0
                                  AND AG.ERROR = 0 ))
```

its preventing the optimizer from using indexes efficiently  .
trying to achieve the following results

```
    Title                               AdvertiserHierarchyId       Counter
    trcom65@travelrepublic.co.uk        15908                       1
    paul570@travelrepublic.co.uk        37887                       1
    es88@travelrepublic.co.uk           37383                       1
    it004@travelrepublic.co.uk          27006                       1
    011                                 10526                       1
    013                                 10528                       1
    033                                 12013                       1
    062                                 17380                       1
    076                                 20505                       1
```

this is a count of the dirty tinyint column

```
    Dirty   total
    0       36340607
    1       117569
    2       873553
    3       59
```

that links to a static reason table

```
    DirtyReasonId   Title
    0               Nothing
    1               Overnight Engine
    2               End To End
    3               Overnight And End To End
    4               Pause Resume
    5               Overnight Engine and Paused
    6               Overnight Engine E2E and Paused
    7               All Three
```

Comment: Is @DirtyReason declared as BIT? Could you show a very abbreviated data sample and desired results? (This looks familiar. :-))

Comment: How many flags exist, and what's the datatype for `Dirty`?

Comment: @aaron Yes indeed it is!!! I was testing a number of rewritten stored procs and was not getting the desired results, I think I have mis understood the logic performed by a Bitwise

Comment: Can you post a quick example showing the right data types, a few rows, and the query above that ges the results you're trying to get at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @aaron i have had edit the post, as the last query had variable built from functions etc and was hard to get results as an intermediate process.  the dirty field is a small int, let me know if you want me to post these structures to sqlfiddle.com still  ...   ive tried to format the implicit joins, lack of dbo. this time to avoid clouding the waters!

Comment: Can you show the values of `Dirty` in those rows? And the values of `Dirty` in rows that aren't returned in the results? Step back from the question and read it. Tell me if you think the solution would be obvious without additional knowledge you have that you haven't shared with us. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking specifically about the use of the BITWISE AND operator, I believe you are correct, and it's unlikely that SQL Server sees that as sargable, at least, not with an index with Dirty as a leading column.

You are showing only the lowest two bits in use (maximum value of Dirty is 3), yet you are testing the lowest three bits.

So, `AC.Dirty > 0` would return an equivalent result, given that 3 is largest value of Dirty. But there is a possibility that other (higher-order) bits are set, for example Dirty could be set to 8. So, if the intent is to check ONLY the lowest three bits, then we need to ensure that we test only the three lowest-order bits.  This expression would do that, and one of the predicates is sargable:

```
( AC.Dirty > 0 AND AC.Dirty % 8 > 0 )
```

This basically tests first whether ANY bits in `AC.Dirty` are set, and then checks if any of the last three bits are set. (We're using the MODULO division operator to return the remainder of AC.Dirty divided by 8, which will of course return an integer value between 0 and 7. If we get a zero, then we know that none of the lower three bits are set, else we know at least one of the bits is set.

Just to be clear: the predicate on `AC.Dirty > 0` is redundant. It's included here in case you are wanting to make sure that database can at least consider using an existing index with `Dirty` as a leading column.

---

I will mention that another option to consider would be adding a persisted COMPUTED COLUMN on the expression, and create an index on it. But that seems a bit overkill for what you need here.

---

If you are asking specifically about getting an index used on table `admanAdvertiserCreative_tbl` (AC), then likely your best candidate would be covering index on `(AdvertiserAdGroupId, Error, Dirty)`.

---

The SQL rewrite below should return equivalent results, perhaps with better performance (depending on your data distribution, indexes, et al.)

Basically, replace the EXISTS (correlated subquery) with a JOIN to a subquery. The subquery returns distinct values of CAMP.ParentAdvertiserHierarchyId, which is the column you referenced to correlate the subquery.

This may or may not make use of any indexes, depending on what indexes are available. (It's likely have clustered unique indexes on the primary keys, and have non-clustered indexes on the foreign keys, which should help join performance.)

Untested:

```
SELECT  ACC.Title,
        ACC.AdvertiserHierarchyId,
        1 AS Counter
FROM    admanAdvertiserHierarchy_tbl ACC
JOIN    dbo.admanAdvertiserObjectType_tbl AOT 
        ON AOT.AdvertiserObjectTypeId = ACC.AdvertiserObjectTypeId
JOIN   (SELECT    CAMP.ParentAdvertiserHierarchyId
          FROM    dbo.admanAdvertiserHierarchy_tbl CAMP
          JOIN    dbo.admanAdvertiserAdGroup_tbl AG 
            ON    CAMP.AdvertiserHierarchyId = AG.AdvertiserHierarchyId
          JOIN    dbo.admanAdvertiserCreative_tbl AC 
            ON    AC.AdvertiserAdGroupId = AG.AdvertiserAdGroupId
         WHERE    CAMP.ERROR = 0
           AND    ( AC.Dirty > 0 AND AC.Dirty % 8 > 0 )
           AND    AC.ERROR = 0
           AND    AG.ERROR = 0 )
         GROUP BY CAMP.ParentAdvertiserHierarchyId
       ) c
  ON c.ParentAdvertiserHierarchyId = ACC.AdvertiserHierarchyId
```

Comment: thanks for all the info spencer, the index did exists already. This snippet is part of several exist statements that use the 'dirty' table. I have applied the suggestions here, but the gains are only 1-2%.. I may attempt to split the table into bit columns. thanks

Comment: You've got quite a few joins going on there. The predicate on the Dirty column may not be the performance issue at all. A lack of  clustered indexes, indexes on the primary keys, indexes on the foreign keys, and covering indexes are going to be the "big" problem.